# Generating a random variable in golang using math/rand

Tags: random, go

I'm trying to simulate a coin flip for a program in golang. I'm trying to use `math/rand` and I'm seeding it using `time`.

```
import (
"fmt"
"math/rand"
"time"
)
```

From what I've looked up elsewhere on here and online, my implementation should work:

```
func main() {
    var random int
    var i int
    var j int
    for j != 5 && i != 5 {
        rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
        random = rand.Intn(1)
        if random == 0 {
            i = i + 1
        }
        if random == 1 {
            j = j + 1
        }
    }
fmt.Println(i, j)
}
```

But, each time I run it, random always end up being 0. The seed doesn't change either, which confuses me. Since it's within the loop, shouldn't the time in nanoseconds change each time it's seeded?

Comment: Note also that the time doesn't change in the Go playground.

Comment: Just be aware that math/rand generates pseudo random numbers not real random numbers. (...) And these pseudo random number are vulnerable to many cryptoanalytic attacks - like what happened to PlayStation (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generator_attack).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't reseed in the loop, do it only once.

[`rand.Intn(n)`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Intn) returns a value >= 0 and < n. So `rand.Intn(1)` can only return 0, you want `rand.Intn(2)` to get 0 or 1.

Fixed code:
http://play.golang.org/p/3D9osMzRRb

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh thanks! But why would I want to seed it just once? Wouldn't this give me the same result each time?

Comment: @agoedken I don't think you understand what [seeding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_seed) is and why it's done.